# How to correct AngularJS 1.3.5 module loading error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple html page with angularJS. Here is my html page code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>ShowTrackr</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
  <link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Nav Bar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top"
     role="navigation" bs-navbar>
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film"></span>
      Show<strong>Trackr</strong></a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li data-match-route="/$"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li data-match-route="/add"><a href="/add">Add</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" ng-if="!currentUser">
    <li data-match-route="/login"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
    <li data-match-route="/signup"><a href="/signup">Sign up</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" ng-if="currentUser">
    <li class="navbar-text" ng-bind="currentUser.email"></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="logout()">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div ng-view></div>

<script src="vendor/angular.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-strap.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-strap.tpl.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have an app.js to configure angularjs module and load some angular module :

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ngMessages', 'ngRoute', 'mgcrea.ngStrap'])
  .config(function() {

  });
```

When i load my html file in browser, i have an angularjs error :

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'MyApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$injector/nomod?p0=MyApp
    at http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:63:12
    at http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:1747:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:1671:38)
    at module (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:1745:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:4050:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:322:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:4034:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:3960:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:1434:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:1455:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=Error%3A%2…otstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fvendor%2Fangular.js%3A1455%3A12)
    at http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:63:12
    at http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:1747:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:1671:38)
    at module (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:1745:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:4050:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:322:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:4034:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:3960:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:1434:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:1455:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=MyApp&p1=Error%3A%2…otstrap%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fvendor%2Fangular.js%3A1455%3A12)
    at http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:63:12
    at http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:4073:15
    at forEach (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:322:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:4034:5)
    at createInjector (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:3960:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:1434:20)
    at bootstrap (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:1455:12)
    at angularInit (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:1349:5)
    at http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:25912:5
    at HTMLDocument.trigger (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular.js:2722:7)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:63
(anonymous) @ angular.js:4073
forEach @ angular.js:322
loadModules @ angular.js:4034
createInjector @ angular.js:3960
doBootstrap @ angular.js:1434
bootstrap @ angular.js:1455
angularInit @ angular.js:1349
(anonymous) @ angular.js:25912
trigger @ angular.js:2722
eventHandler @ angular.js:2992
```

I use angularjs 1.3.5 version. Where am i wrong please ?

Comment: all the references are loaded correctly?

Comment: No my app.js is not loaded. I don't understand because it's a the same level as index.html. Others js library are loaded correctly

Comment: yeah let's see it in private message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your app.js is loading, if its not loading, try to clear the cache,

Try to save all the fields and restart the server. It should work.